# Error while splitting PDBQT file

Tags: proteins

I am trying to split to a pdbqt file containing 178 compounds into individual pdbqt files. I have been using the Autodock Vina_split.exe file to split the multiple entry file however I keep running into the following error. What can I do to prevent the error.

[image]

Comment: (A) Empty file? Does the file open in PyMol? Also, you can always split it there with `split_states`.

(B) Is the file really called `output.pdbqt` or is it `output.pdbqt.txt` and Windows is hiding the extension?

Comment: There could be many reasons. Maybe lack of permissions or the space in the path. Can you open the file with a different program? Are you on Linux or Windows etc.